# Decrypting a python message using xor

Tags: python, encryption, xor

Hello I am starting in the world of Python and related to encryption, I am doing an exercise that consists of making a script that works on the encrypted message and the key to get the message in plain text. The decrypted message has to be displayed in ASCII.
The problem is that I got to this part and I can't find the way to show me the decrypted plain text.

```
message = '9c8d968f8b90a08f868b979091a0c5bb'
key = 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff'
m_bytes = message.encode()
k_bytes = key.encode()
length = len(message)

result_xor = []

for i in range(length):
    result = m_bytes[i] ^ k_bytes[i]
    result_xor.append(result)

result_xor_bytes = bytes(result_xor)
string_ascii = result_xor_bytes.decode('ascii')
print(result_xor_bytes)
print(string_ascii)
```

the result I get is as follows

```
b'_\x05^\x02_P^\x00^\x04_V\x07V^\x00^P^\x04_Q_V_W\x07V\x05S\x04\x04'
_^_P^ ^_VV^ ^P^_Q_V_WVS
```

Comment: Are your key and message supposed to be hexidecimal? That's different than the ASCII decoding and encoding you're doing....

Comment: Do note that `k_bytes` isn't the byte `0xff` repeated, it's the byte `0x66` repeated (UTF-8 encoding for the lowercase letter f). It that intentional?

Comment: The problem statement indicates that I was given everything in hexadecimal. I have to display the decoded message in ASCII. It ends with ":D"

Sorry if I can't understand quickly, I'm just learning about this topic. Besides, English is not my native language.

Comment: Decode your hex strings with `binascii.unhexlify`, rather than their `encode` method. You might still want `decode` at the end, to get ASCII results, but you could call `binascii.hexlify` if you need the hex values of the result instead.

Answer (score 1):

After searching all afternoon, I decided to do it another way.

```
# Se asigna el mensaje cifrado y la key a sus respectivas variables
message = "9c8d968f8b90a08f868b979091a0c5bb"
key = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"

# Convierto el mensaje y la clave de hex a bytes
mensaje_cifrado_bytes = bytes.fromhex(message)
clave_bytes = bytes.fromhex(key)

# Utilizo la operación XOR entre el mensaje cifrado y la clave
mensaje_descifrado_bytes = bytes([a ^ b for (a, b) in zip(mensaje_cifrado_bytes, clave_bytes)])

# Convierto el resultado de la operación XOR a ASCII para obtener el mensaje descifrado
mensaje_descifrado = mensaje_descifrado_bytes.decode('ascii')

# Se imprime mensaje descifrado
print(mensaje_descifrado)
```

This way it gives me the message I was looking for.